# How can I use the float version of nfp()?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to use the `nfp()` function in Processing to present my floats on screen with a certain number of decimal places. In [the manual page for this function](https://processing.org/reference/nfp_.html), it says that

> There are two versions: one for formatting floats, and one for formatting ints.

However, when I'm trying to use the function with a float variable (and an int variable for the number of decimal points), I get the following error:

> The function "nfp()" expects parameters like; "nfp(int,int)".

Am I missing something here? How can I access the float version of the function?

Comment: Do you input the float with an "f" after the number? Otherwise it may be interpreted as a double. If you pass it as a variable, what happens if you parse it as float (float)myVar ?

Comment: Okay I just tried out myself, it seems, that it just accepts the first value as float, if you also give the two more parameters (for left and right) to the function. Which makes sense, since with a float you can tell zeros before and after the dot.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can run. This could be as simple as a single line of code in your case.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Thanks! That worked! Still strange that this isn't mentioned in the manual page though.

Comment: @Jankapunkt You should turn your comment into an answer. This was a weird issue, but I think it's just a result of the reference being slightly misleading because it doesn't mention the fact that if the first parameter is a `float`, then you must provide both a `left` and a `right` parameter as well.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nfp function formats numbers into strings and adds zeros to it.

This is done for integers always before the given number, which is why the function `npf(int, int)` requires only one more parameter for the digits.

The function `nfp(float, int)` does not work. The function requires for a float input two integers: `nfp(float, int, int)`.

This is, since it needs to know, how many digits will be added before the dot (left) and how many should be added after the dot (right).

`nfp(1.2, 1, 2)` will lead to +1.20

`nfp(1.2, 2, 1)` will lead to +01.2

**Not a big issue? NO! This is a perfect example to learn two things:**

1. It is important that thrown Errors have to make clear what the problem really is about.
2. Documentation has to be clear about the usage of functions, especially, when they accept different variations of parameters.

If both are not considered well enough, when designing a framework, developers (like op in this case) get stuck on problems that could have been easily avoided.

Comment: Great answer! I totally agree with the sentiment at the end.